# How to remove dimensions in numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

How can I change array:

```
np.array([[[a,b,c], [d,e,f]], [[g, h, i], [j, k, l]]])
```

to this format:

```
np.array([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l])
```

Comment: What you want to do is better not called 'removing dimensions'; but 'flattening'.  One could also 'remove dimensions' from arrays both technically, and, given, it were numbers, not letters, algebraically by certain kind of contraction, but that is not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to use [numpy.ndarray.flatten](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)

There is also a parameter that determines whether to flatten in row-major or column-major order or preserve the ordering.

From the docs I linked:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
>>> a.flatten()
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a.flatten('F')
array([1, 3, 2, 4])
```